# Call Windows Diashow via batch

Tags: windows, cmd

can someone tell me how I can call a Windows Diashow from a batchfile for a specific Filepath?
Or alternativelxy start the windows photo show in fullscreen mode.

I tried these for Fullscreen mode:

```
%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen C:\test

rundll32 "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen  C:\test
```

But the fullscreen part does not work. Maybe there is a parameter for the Diashow...

I need this for a public display where the picture files are updated every 15 Minutes.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Can't you simply double-click the photo file?

Comment: at a public display I don't want to click it every 15 Minutes, especially at night shift time.